# Keyboard shortcut inside a module to call itself

Tags: excel, vba, module, userform, shortcut

I'm creating an excel module to export any table inside a workbook as .csv

My module generate a UserForm where the user can chose which table to export inside a combobox and then click 'export'

Everything is working perfectly, but I have to create a button in my workbook and call my module on click.

However I want to keep it very simple to setup inside any workbook by just import the module and run it with a keyboard shortcut '''Ctrl+R''' for example.

I search a lot about that but I never find something, Is it something possible?

Comment: You can apply a trick. Use macro recorder and record a simple macro with keyboard shortcut `Ctrl+R` then copy and paste your working codes inside that macro. Now you can call your codes by keyboard shortcut.

Comment: Yes, it's smart but I need to do this for every workbook right? In my case I need to make a standalone module.

Comment: Hi, how about using "mother" workbook with shortcut, and then run code inside other workbook by selecting it?. Just like running code in workbook.name(1) and changing things in workbook.name(2).

Comment: It's still smart, but impossible to ask my co-workers to always have 2 workbooks in the same folder to export a .csv. I want to give the module and by importing it in your workbook, you can run the module by pressing CTRL+R, without any other setup from the user

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can what you want to. First import your module to your new excel workbook and then assign keyboard shortcut to Workbook_Open event by copying code to ThisWorkbook area.

```
Sub MyMacro()
    MsgBox ("ok")
End Sub
```

In ThisWorkbook area (which is in Microsoft Excel Objects / Project Window)

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Application.MacroOptions Macro:="MyMacro", Description:="", ShortcutKey:= _
        "a"
End Sub
```

This code assign Ctrl+"Defined_Letter" shortcut to your MyMacro macro. In this case, the code's shortcut is [Ctrl+a].